# How to class members to table columns in pydapper?

Tags: python, pydapper

I have an existing DB and want to try pydapper, but how to change map classes' fields to table columns (example: class have Name field but it maps to NOME_DESCRICAO)? How I do that (which I already solved in dapper.net)?